# remove select option with jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm sure that some variation of this question has been answered, but I'm not great a JS.  My goal is that I have a select field that is populated by products from my cms (wordpress/woocommerce) that I need to filter out dates that are in the past.

This is the JS I was helped with in making:
It's supposed to work on a select field being generated and results in this code:

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var date = todayDate.getDate();
    var month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = todayDate.getFullYear();
    var mamkestring = date+'-'+month+'-'+year;
    console.log(mamkestring);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('[name="attribute_pa_shipping-date"]').find('option').each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if(value != ''){
                var end = new Date(value);
                var diff = new Date(end - todayDate);   
                var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
                console.log(days);
                if(days <= 0){
                    $(this).hide();
                    //$(this).css('display','none');
                }
            }
        });
    },1500);
    
    $('select:not([name="attribute_pa_shipping-date"])').on('change',function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('[name="attribute_pa_shipping-date"]').find('option').each(function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                if(value != ''){
                    var end = new Date(value);
                    var diff = new Date(end - todayDate);   
                    var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
                    console.log(days);
                    if(days <= 0){
                      $(this).hide();
                      //$(this).css('display','none');
                    }
                }
            });
        },1500);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_shipping-date" class="" name="attribute_pa_shipping-date" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_shipping-date" data-show_option_none="yes">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="2-17-2021" class="attached enabled">2/17/2021</option>
    <option value="3-3-2021" class="attached enabled">3/3/2021</option>
    <option value="3-17-2021" class="attached enabled">3/17/2021</option>
    <option value="3-24-2021" class="attached enabled">3/24/2021</option>
    <option value="3-31-2021" class="attached enabled">3/31/2021</option>
    <option value="3-10-2021" class="attached enabled">3/10/2021</option>
    <option value="4-7-2021" class="attached enabled">4/7/2021</option>
    <option value="4-14-2021" class="attached enabled">4/14/2021</option>
    <option value="4-21-2021" class="attached enabled">4/21/2021</option>
    <option value="4-28-2021" class="attached enabled">4/28/2021</option>
    <option value="5-5-2021" class="attached enabled">5/5/2021</option>
    <option value="5-12-2021" class="attached enabled">5/12/2021</option>
    <option value="5-19-2021" class="attached enabled">5/19/2021</option>
    <option value="5-26-2021" class="attached enabled">5/26/2021</option>
</select>
```

So the goal would be the first line right now (2-17-2021) would be gone from my visible list because it's gone.

I've tried replacing

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).css('display','none');
```

with

```
$(this).remove();
```

or

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

again, I'm not great at JS so it's basically just trial and error,  but the only thing that seems to start to work is `$(this).prop('disabled', true);` and then adding a bit of css:

```
option:disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

the disabled seems to not allow the item to be checked but doesn't hide it, so i tried adding the css.

The problem is that it still loads with the 2/17/2021 date but when I choose the selector its not in the dropdown.  However when I choose a different date, then the 2/17/2021 comes back as an option when I check the dropdown again.

UPDATE it may be a browswer issue?  the count doesn't seem to work in firefox which is why it's not hiding.[image]

Comment: i have edited your code and put it in snippet.(i have commented your line with css display none, because .hide() does the samething)..... so i dont see error in your code, the line is not visible.. so if you want to remove the line just replace .hide() by remove()

Comment: @Frenchy  I think the problem is that it works in Chrome but not in firefox.  You're right that it works in Chrome, but still is not working when I test in firefox

Comment: ok i see that..i think `-` is the problem for firefox..see my answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a problem on firefox when using date with `-` so just replace `-` by `/` and all is ok (**or work with .text() instead val()**)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var date = todayDate.getDate();
    var month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = todayDate.getFullYear();
    var mamkestring = date+'-'+month+'-'+year;
    console.log(mamkestring);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('[name="attribute_pa_shipping-date"]').find('option').each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val().replace(/-/g, '/');
            if(value != ''){
                var end = new Date(value);
                var diff = new Date(end - todayDate) 
                var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
                console.log(days);
                if(days <= 0){
                    $(this).hide();
                    //$(this).css('display','none');
                }
            }
        });
    },1500);
    
    $('select:not([name="attribute_pa_shipping-date"])').on('change',function(){
        setTimeout(function(){

            $('[name="attribute_pa_shipping-date"]').find('option').each(function(){
                var value = $(this).val().replace(/-/g, '/');
 
                if(value != ''){
                    var end = new Date(value);
                    var diff = new Date(end - todayDate);  
                    
                    var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
                    console.log(days);
                    if(days <= 0){
                      $(this).hide();
                      //$(this).css('display','none');
                    }
                }
            });
        },1500);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_shipping-date" class="" name="attribute_pa_shipping-date" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_shipping-date" data-show_option_none="yes">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="2-17-2021" class="attached enabled">2/17/2021</option>
    <option value="3-3-2021" class="attached enabled">3/3/2021</option>
    <option value="3-17-2021" class="attached enabled">3/17/2021</option>
    <option value="3-24-2021" class="attached enabled">3/24/2021</option>
    <option value="3-31-2021" class="attached enabled">3/31/2021</option>
    <option value="3-10-2021" class="attached enabled">3/10/2021</option>
    <option value="4-7-2021" class="attached enabled">4/7/2021</option>
    <option value="4-14-2021" class="attached enabled">4/14/2021</option>
    <option value="4-21-2021" class="attached enabled">4/21/2021</option>
    <option value="4-28-2021" class="attached enabled">4/28/2021</option>
    <option value="5-5-2021" class="attached enabled">5/5/2021</option>
    <option value="5-12-2021" class="attached enabled">5/12/2021</option>
    <option value="5-19-2021" class="attached enabled">5/19/2021</option>
    <option value="5-26-2021" class="attached enabled">5/26/2021</option>
</select>
```

Firefox asks a Date in format RFC822 or ISO 8601, chrome is less strong

Comment: this makes sense and definitely works here.  doesn't work on my site though. :(

Comment: you have another problem..so when date are used with `-` no problem for chrome or firefox here with the solution in snippet